# Can't get Enterprise Search 8.6.2 to run

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7, elastic-enterprise-search

I have `Elasticsearch 8.6.2` working and can log into `Kibana 8.6.2` web UI but I can't get `Enterprise Search 8.6.2` to work. Seeing this in the `app-server.log` it make mention of `localhost:5601` which is coming from Kibana but the word localhost is not in any of the YML config files. Everything is installed on the same server and I have replaced localhost with the IP address of the server.

```
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.489+00:00][95252][4004][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Elasticsearch will be used for authentication
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.495+00:00][95252][4004][app-server][INFO]: Elasticsearch looks healthy and configured correctly to run Enterprise Search
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.496+00:00][95252][4004][app-server][INFO]: Performing pre-flight checks for Kibana running on http://localhost:5601...
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.806+00:00][95252][4004][es][DEBUG]: {
  "request": {
    "url": "http://localhost:5601/api/status",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "[FILTERED]",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "Faraday v1.10.2"
    },
    "params": null,
    "body": null
  },
  "exception": "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/lib/middleware/request_logging_middleware.class:55: Connect to localhost:5601 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)\n",
  "duration": 302.5,
  "stack": [
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:79:in `check_kibana_connection_with_retries!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:34:in `check_kibana_connection!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:18:in `block in run!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:17:in `run!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:13:in `run!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:313:in `configure_kibana!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:271:in `configure!'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/config/application.class:20:in `<main>'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/config/application.rb:1:in `<main>'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli/command.class:36:in `initialize'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli/command.class:10:in `new'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli/command.class:10:in `run_and_exit'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:148:in `run_supported_command'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:130:in `run_command'",
    "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:112:in `run!'",
    "bin/enterprise-search-internal:15:in `<main>'"
  ]
}
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.807+00:00][95252][4004][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Kibana backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2023-04-24T22:39:49.811+00:00][95252][4004][app-server][DEBUG]: [pre-flight] Kibana connection error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/kibana_checks.class:128: Connect to localhost:5601 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

`Enterprise Search 8.6.2 is not starting`

Comment: In `kibana.yml` if you look carefully, you find the following line: `#server.port: 5601` which is in the form of `comment`. Because by `default` `kibana` runs in `port:5601`. If you want to change this, uncomment that line by setting your desired port number

Comment: I looked carefully and server.port: 5601 is in the kibana.yml and not a comment. thanks```server.port: 5601  server.host: "12.345.67.890" 
  server.publicBaseUrl: "http://12.345.67.890:5601"  elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://12.345.67.890:9200"]  elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"  elasticsearch.password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/etc/kibana/certs/http_ca.crt" ]  pid.file: /run/kibana/kibana.pid```